# Sentry on Laravel 4 with MAMP

Tags: laravel, mamp, cartalyst-sentry

I'm using Laravel on MAMP PRO (PHP 5.4).  Both are vanilla install and I got Laravel working okay.

Next, Installed Sentry.

Inside of a login function on controller:

```
$user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false); // this works.  I can see the $user
```

But then upon an immediate redirect I use a filter:

```
Route::filter('auth.admin', function()
{
    var_dump(Sentry::check()); // ** this gives me a bool(false);
    die();

    if ( ! Sentry::check())
    {
        return Redirect::route('admin.login');
    }
});
```

So, I'm assuming that maybe there is a cookie that is not being set?

Answer (score 1):

Solved...

For anyone else with this issue, this is a summary of the most common solutions on the Internet as well as how I solved my issue.  I'm on MAMP/OSX, but this apparently made zero difference as I literally put up a vagrant/virtualbox and still had the same issue.

1. ** Set 'domain' => 'yourdomain.com' in your config/session.php.  EVEN IF YOU ARE ON A SUB DOMAIN like a.b.c.yourdomain.com, use ONLY the root domain (yourdomain.com) in your 'domain' variable as I just wrote it. ** This was my issue.
2. Make sure your session storage folder has write permissions.
3. Make sure you have a >0 lifetime in your session.php
4. Make sure you don't have whitespaces after any closing PHP which could cause the application not to shut down properly.
5. Try Switching between database sessions and file sessions.
6. As a last resort, try upgrade to 4.2, if possible.  4.1 had a known issue (as referenced in google).
7. Your issue is may no be with Laravel OR Sentry.  It's probably a file or configuration issue as illustrated above.  I pulled my hair out tracking this from Sentry to Laravel to Cookies to Session to Blah... Only to realize that it was finally a cookie issue which was caused by me not setting my ROOT domain (I was using the full